# How to Implement Multiple User Details Service in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have created Security For Each UserDetails. And Added Login Page url for each as below.Now I want all the login page to be public and other endpoints that doesnot start with the user or business-segment to be public too.For more references [I am following this documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points).

```
@Configuration
@Order(3)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BusinessSegmentSecurity {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainForBusinessSegment(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity.securityMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/business-segment/**"));
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/business-segment/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/business-segment/**").authenticated());
        httpSecurity.formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/business-segment/auth/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/business-segment/auth/login")
                .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/business-segment"))
                .logout(httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer -> httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutSuccessUrl("/business-segment/auth/login"));
        httpSecurity.userDetailsService(new BusinessSegmentService());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurity {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainForGuest(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.securityMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/**"));
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry -> authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UserSecurity {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity.securityMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/user/**"));
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/user/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated());
        httpSecurity.formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/user/auth/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/user/auth/login")
                .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user"))
                .logout(httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer -> httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutSuccessUrl("/user/auth/login"));
        httpSecurity.userDetailsService(new CustomUserDetailService());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```